# How to replace a value of smaller length than one with bigger length in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which I read as an pandas dataframe. I wanna tokenize one column of the dataset. My tokenized value is a list with bigger length than my original cell value.

**Error message:**

`ValueError: Replacement lists must match in length. Expecting 1 got 72`

How can I do this replacement in my dataframe?

**Code where I tried to iterate over and replace my values**

```py
trainData = pd.read_csv("data/train.csv")
test = trainData[0:100]
CODEBERTA_LANGUAGE_ID = "huggingface/CodeBERTa-language-id"
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(CODEBERTA_LANGUAGE_ID)
for i in test["code"]:
    test["code"] = test["code"].replace([i], tokenizer.encode(i))
```

**Image example of my dataframe**

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: maybe you want `test['code'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.encode(x)]`

Comment: Yes this solved the problem. I cannot accept this comment as an answer. What is the stackoverflow convention if an comment is the accepted answer? @Chris

Comment: Maybe post at the bottom of the question that 'this line of code worked', and close the question?

Comment: @baileythegreen - no, answers never belong in the question space. One can self-answer however, by posting an answer in the answer space.

Comment: @BigBen, interesting. I suppose that does have the advantage of it being clear there is an answer from the list of questions.

Comment: .... exactly, this is a Q&A site.

Comment: It's a comment because I'm almost sure it's a dupe, but there may not be a direct match - so for the sake of helping you out, it's a  comment, but I would personally close the question.